# Align content to rtl in tinymce using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I'm Developing a Wordpress plugin and i added a button to tinymce interface,  when user press it the direction of the text convert from right to left .
i tried to do the following but with no luck

```
        tinymce.get('#tinymce').getBody().dir ="rtl";
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Codex article about [Writing a Post in RTL Language](http://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support#Writing_a_Post_in_RTL_Language) recommends the use of the plugin [WP-RTL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rtl/), which

> [...] enables the text directions functionality that exist already in the original TinyMCE editor which allow writing texts in Left-to-Right and Right-to-Left directions in the same post (or page) for languages like Arabic, Persian and Hebrew.

Its code is dead simple:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WP-RTL
Plugin URI: http://www.fadvisor.net/blog/2008/10/wp-rtl/
Description: Adds two buttons to the TinyMCE editor to enable writing text in Left to Right (LTR) and Right to Left (RTL) directions.
Version: 0.3
Author: Fahad Alduraibi
Author URI: http://www.fadvisor.net/blog/
*/

add_action( "init", "tinymce_bidi_addbuttons" );

function tinymce_bidi_addbuttons() {
    if( !current_user_can ( 'edit_posts' ) && !current_user_can ( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if( get_user_option ( 'rich_editing' ) == 'true' ) {
        add_filter( "mce_external_plugins", "tinymce_bidi_plugin" );
        add_filter( "mce_buttons", "tinymce_bidi_buttons" );
    }
}
function tinymce_bidi_buttons($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, "separator", "ltr", "rtl");
    return $buttons;
}

function tinymce_bidi_plugin($plugin_array) {
    if (get_bloginfo('version') < 3.9) {
        $plugin_array['directionality'] = includes_url('js/tinymce/plugins/directionality/editor_plugin.js');
    } else {
        $plugin_array['directionality'] = includes_url('js/tinymce/plugins/directionality/plugin.min.js');
    }
    return $plugin_array;
}
```

And this is what it does:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I like the gif animation, it's very informative to see it in action (+1)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that there is already a plugin that you can initialize that deals with directionality in TinyMCE [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:directionality)

Is this what your looking for or am I missing something?

PS: its not clear as to whether or not it works within the editor, So it may not, but It's worth a shot I think if it sounds like what your looking for.